# Response.Write not showing on flags

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I can avoid response .write what would be the alternative ?

Can someone please tell why this response message is not showing up ? it used to until recently.

```
DirectorySearcher objADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

objADSearcher.SearchRoot = de;
objADSearcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + item + ")";
SearchResult results = objADSearcher.FindOne();
if (results.ToString() != "")
{
    int flags = Convert.ToInt32(results.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString());
    //for reference results.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString().Equals("514");

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002))
    {
        Response.Write("<script> alert ('" + "Account Disabled for more then 90 days, please call helpdesk at 1 xx.xx.xxx to activate your account" + "') </script>");
    }
```

Comment: The code itself works as expected. If you debug and step through, do both `if` statements definitely succeed and you get to the `Response.Write` line? And if you then View Source in the browser is the `<script>` tag rendered in the page and no JavaScript errors?

Comment: BTW I'm sure `objADSearcher.FindOne()` returns `null` if nothing is found, so `if (results.ToString() != "")` would throw a `NullReferenceException` - a simple `if (results != null)` looks better

Comment: Flags return value 514. debugger goes twice over response.write without showing any message. all this from Firefox. if I try on IE8 I got this javascript error ;Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Unable to parse the message received from the server. This error can have several causes: Response modified by calls to Response.Write (), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace activation.
 Details: Error parsing near '<script> alert (' Acc '.

Comment: This is just very poorly written code: `results.ToString()`? `flags & 0x0002`? How is anyone supposed to figure this out without stepping through the debugger and refactoring code?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it

Comment: Also, If you're doing this from a code behind I wouldn't use Response.Write, I would register the alert javascript something like "ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType, "Alert", "alert('this is a test');", true);"

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to using a Response.Write from the code behind would be to register the javascript like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType, "Alert", "alert('this is a test');", true);
```